# Difference between two complexity recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

Following are two recurrence relations

1. T(n)= T(n/2)+T(n/2) + C
2. T(n)= T(n/2)*T(n/2) + C

Will both the have the same time complexity? Can I write both recurrence relations like this?

3. T(n) = 2T(n/2) + C

Comment: of course not!!! why!???

Comment: 2T(n/2) doesn't mean function T will be called twice.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is obviously the same as (3): T(n/2) + T(n/2) = 2 T(n/2). That's elementary math.

(1) is not the same as (2), and it shouldn't be difficult to see that the solution to these relations is completely different. (1) = (3) means that for data that's twice as large, the complexity measure is about twice as large — linear complexity. (2) means that for data that's twice as large, the complexity is squared — exponential complexity.

Comment: Thank you so much for you kind response. If i use master theorm to compute complexity of T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1 it comes to Theeta(n) or I solve it using back substitution method.

Can you please help me in solving T(n) = T(n/2)*T(n/2) + 1 ?
I think complexity won't be exponential but it will be O(n^2), please correct me if I am wrong. thank you!